# Use Proc or Module

Tags: ruby, rspec, module, proc

I want to use Proc, but I have no idea how to call the Proc in the array iterator. If possible, could you also suggest how to do this with MODULES?

esp. the part "result << (p.call(x))

```
def translate (str)
    word = str.split(" ")
    result = []

    word.each do |x| 
        result << (p.call(x))
    end

    result.join(" ")
end

p = Proc.new do |single_word|
    temp_array = single_word.split('')
    num = ( single_word =~ /[aeiou]/)
    num.times do
        temp = temp_array.shift
        temp_array << temp
    end
    temp_array << "ay"
    temp_array.join("")
end

translate("best")
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understood your purposes correctly, but may be just:

```
def translate(str, p)
  ...
end
...
translate("best", p)
```

Also this can be done with &block but I do not see why do you need proc or block in the example at all.

Comment: OMG...I forgot this important rule, but what if I just want to call translate("best") without "p" parameter?

Comment: Is there anyway to do that? Do you know how to do it with module method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a block of code from within a method, without needing to pass it around (meaning it is not dynamically decided) - why not simply use a method?

```
def translate (str)
    word = str.split(" ")
    result = []

    word.each do |x| 
        result << translate_word(x)
    end

    result.join(" ")
end

def translate_word(single_word)
    temp_array = single_word.split('')
    num = ( single_word =~ /[aeiou]/)
    num.times do
        temp = temp_array.shift
        temp_array << temp
    end
    temp_array << "ay"
    temp_array.join("")
end

translate("best")
```

if you want to declare it in a module, you can do it either by including it:

**word_translator.rb**

```
module WordTranslator
 def translate_word(single_word)
    temp_array = single_word.split('')
    num = ( single_word =~ /[aeiou]/)
    num.times do
        temp = temp_array.shift
        temp_array << temp
    end
    temp_array << "ay"
    temp_array.join("")
  end
end
```

**translator.rb**

```
require 'word_translator.rb'

class Translator
  include WordTranslator

  def translate (str)
    word = str.split(" ")
    result = []

    word.each do |x| 
        result << translate_word(x)
    end

    result.join(" ")
  end
end
```

Or, declare it as a class method:

**word_translator.rb**

```
module WordTranslator
 def self.translate_word(single_word)
    temp_array = single_word.split('')
    num = ( single_word =~ /[aeiou]/)
    num.times do
        temp = temp_array.shift
        temp_array << temp
    end
    temp_array << "ay"
    temp_array.join("")
  end
end
```

**translator.rb**

```
require 'word_translator.rb'

class Translator

  def translate (str)
    word = str.split(" ")
    result = []

    word.each do |x| 
        result << WordTranslator.translate_word(x)
    end

    result.join(" ")
  end
end
```